# Immovable property not working in phaser

Tags: phaser-framework, phase

Here is my code regarding tilesprite & a player, player should not pass through tilesprite but unfortunately my code is not working, i tried all ways but couldn't achieve the desired result, i don't know why `tile2.body.immovable=true;` flag not working.

```
var main = {

    preload: function () {
        this.game.load.image('ground', 'images/ground.jpg');
        this.game.load.image('bg', 'images/gabg.jpg');
        this.game.load.atlasJSONHash('mover', 'images/sheet.png', 'images/sprites.json');

    },

    create: function () {
        this.game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);

        cursor = this.game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
        tile1 = game.add.tileSprite(0, 10, 1365, 582, 'bg');
        tile2 = game.add.tileSprite(0, 590, 1366, 91, 'ground');

        player = this.game.add.sprite(50, 550, 'mover');
        player.frame = 0;
        player.anchor.setTo(0.5, 0.5);
        while (i < 11) {
            anim.push(i)
            i++;
        }
        player.animations.add('move', anim, 20, true);

        this.game.physics.arcade.enable(player);
        this.game.physics.arcade.enable(tile2);
        tile2.body.immovable = true;
        tile2.body.allowGravity = false;
        player.body.gravity.y = 800;
    },

    update: function () {
        this.game.physics.arcade.collide(tile2, player);
        tile1.tilePosition.x += -1;
        tile2.tilePosition.x += -4;
        this.move();
    },

    move: function () {
        if (cursor.up.isDown) {
            player.body.velocity.y = -200;
            player.animations.stop('move');
        }

        else {
            player.animations.play('move');
        }
    },

};

var game = new Phaser.Game(1366, 768, Phaser.CANVAS, 'gamediv');
this.game.state.add('main', main);
this.game.state.start('main');

var anim = [];
var cursor, i=0;
var tile1;
var tile2;
var player;
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Phaser are you using? Could it be related to this bug in 2.3.0?

http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/13856-problem-with-collide-method-from-physics-arcade-in-different-versions-of-phaser/?p=79032